# Benchmarking Theano

Tags: deep-learning, performance, theano

I sometimes want to benchmark Theano, either to compare different versions of Theano, or to compare two different computing environment with the same version of Theano. Is there any Theano code I could use to benchmark the main functions of Theano? I plan to use Theano only for artificial neural networks (RNN and CNN).

Answer (score 1):

Theano has a `check_blas.py` which can benchmark your BLAS computing capability.

For CNN, try [convnet-benchmarks](https://github.com/soumith/convnet-benchmarks). I used to benchmark tensorflow with it, you can have a try.

For RNN, take a look at [rnn-benchmarks](https://github.com/glample/rnn-benchmarks)